# Resolve strange compiler error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a bunch of lines like this:

```
Dim myNewStringValue As String : myNewStringValue = "Hello"
```

I'm trying to convert them all into multiple lines, i.e. to remove the `:` character, because I don't like that convention.  However, this results in a strange compiler error:

[image]

> "'myN' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
>   level."

Nothing I do after that point clears it up.  Even if I undo all, the error persists.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? Does it contain zero-width whitespace or break characters?

Comment: @CodeCaster -- no.  You can repro it yourself if you want.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the commands on two lines - are you 100% sure it's not an error on a different bit of code?

Comment: @roryap Save the file and open it in Notepad++ to see if there are funny characters.

Comment: All you you please do me a favor and try it.  Just type it in yourselves in the VS2013 IDE.

Comment: @freefaller -- I've included a screen shot showing the error.

Comment: Have you tried a clear and rebuild?  Sometime just the rebuild is not enough to clear everything

Comment: @roryap How have you converted from one to the other? simply selecting `:` and hitting return causes no issues - have you done a find/replace?

Comment: @JamesThorpe -- No I haven't done any conversion.  Find and replace results in the same problem as just deleting the character and hitting the return key.

Comment: @freefaller -- Rebuild doesn't help.

Comment: And I would love to know what the down vote is all about?

Comment: Assuming reopening the project makes the errors go away, what happens if you convert it to `Dim myNewStringValue As String = "Hello"` instead?

Comment: *Rebuild doesn't help*... I presume you mean the "clear and rebuild doesn't help", because it was the clear that I specifically said might be needed

Comment: @freefaller -- Ah, yes, clean and rebuild *does* help.

Comment: @roryap: i guess the downvotes are because people can't reproduce this issue and they think that close/open visual studio fixes it.

Comment: Isn't it always things like this that waste so much time... I hate programming - I just wish the mortgage didn't depend on it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079370/resolve-strange-compiler-error?noredirect=1#comment46393119_29079370) against the question, normally something like this can be resolved by doing a `Clean Solution` and then `Rebuild Solution`.

It is not always enough to *just* do a `Rebuild Solution` on its own.

Comment: Not a problem - one of those ones you can easily waste hours on pulling your hair out

Comment: That's why I love Stack Overflow.

Comment: Shouldn't that be _Clean_ rather than _Clear_?